# How are native functions created in Rhino?

Tags: javascript, rhino, ringojs

I've been looking at the Rhino [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial#JavaScript_host_objects) and [source code](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeGlobal.java) for a clue as to how to implement my own global native function. This task is however more complicated than I expected it to be.

After reading the [code](https://github.com/ringo/ringojs/blob/master/src/org/ringojs/engine/Require.java) of the implementation of the `require` function in RingoJS I believe I need to do something along the following lines:

```
import org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;

public class MyGlobalNativeFunction extends BaseFunction {
    public MyGlobalNativeFunction() {}

    public Object call(Context cx, Scriptable scope, Scriptable thisObj, Object[] args) {
        // implementation of my function
    }

    public int getArity() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Am I on the correct track? A step by step walkthrough on how to achieve this would be great.

Also it would be great if I could use Rhino's `defineClass` function to create my global native function. I'm not too keen on rolling out my own modified version of Rhino just because I want to implement one native function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work, and if you only want to implement a single global function it's a good approach. If you want to implement multiple functions or a host object, there are other approaches.

You'd then use something like this to instantiate your function:

```
scope.defineProperty("myNativeFunction",
                     new MyGlobalNativeFunction(),
                     ScriptableObject.DONTENUM);
```

Check out [RingoGlobal](https://github.com/ringo/ringojs/blob/master/src/org/ringojs/engine/RingoGlobal.java) for how this is done (it also shows how to define multiple functions in one sweep without having to creating a class for each). The [Rhino examples directory](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/tree/master/examples) contains some examples of how to create proper host objects with Rhino.

Comment: I'm assuming `scope` is the global scope, right? Where do I instantiate it and how do I get access to `scope`? I see that `RingoGlobal` has a method called `init`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all You need to init your global scope (init all javascript standard object, functions, etc), next to add your function to this scope as Hannes Wallnöfer wrote.

```
Context cx = Context.enter();  //enter rhino context - bind context with current thread
Scriptable globalScope= cx.initStandardObjects();  //init js standard object in global scope
globalScope.defineProperty("myNativeFunction",
                     new MyGlobalNativeFunction(),
                     ScriptableObject.DONTENUM);
```

and that's it.

Now to call this function invoke:

```
Object result = cx.evaluateString(globalScope, "myNativeFunction()", "<cmd>", 1, null);
```

For more information see: [rhino embedding tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial)